# JavaFX- Getting Entire Row Item for cellFactory()?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Say I have a given `TableView<Person>`. And I have a column with a `LocalDate` type with a set `cellFactory()`.

```
birthdayColumn.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<Person, LocalDate>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            //Person person = ... I want to get entire Person, not just LocalDate item

            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
                setStyle("");
            } else {
                // Format date.
                setText(myDateFormatter.format(item));

                // Style all dates in March with a different color.
                if (item.getMonth() == Month.MARCH) {
                    setTextFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                } else {
                    setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                    setStyle("");
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Is there a way I can get access to the entire `Person` for that record within the `updateItem()` method? I want to use other attributes of `Person` to conditionally format the cell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TableCell has access to both the TableView and it's index within the item list, so you can do:

```
Person person = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());
```

Comment: Thanks Edvin. I was so close! I thought getIndex() had to do with the column index but this worked.